# Multi-image billboard in WiX bootstrapper themes

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

I’m trying to incorporate a billboard element in a WiX theme in order to show the software’s features in a set of images.
What I’m currently using is the [billboard(thmutil)](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/thmutil/billboard.html) element but the documentation is kinda confusing, it says

> Children:
>
> Sequence (min: 1, max: 1)
>
> 1. Image (min: 1, max: 1)

Apparently this billboard element only allows a single `<Image />` element in it (my IDE also suggested the same), then how can I insert multiple images in this billboard element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I was bamboozled by the WiX v3 documentation - You **CAN** insert multiple `<Image />` labels inside a Billboard element.

Yeah, Visual Studio **will** scream at you saying the billboard element `has invalid child element ‘Image’`, but it works.